# How do I connect the Raspberry Pi to a TV with limited input options?

Tags: display, composite-video

I have a new LG TV. This TV has:

- 1 HDMI input that is used for a second display on my desktop PC
- 1 VGA that is used for a second display on my MacBook Pro
- 1 [SCART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART) input (is free)
- 1 compositor with 5 inputs

I tried to connect the Raspberry with the old yellow wire but I couldn't see anything well; additionally the picture was black and white.

How could I connect it to the TV with good quality? Could I use the SCART input, and if so, how?

Comment: According to wikipedia the scart port supports composite but I can't say if your TV does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Composite output defaults to NTSC. If you got a PAL tv it wil display monochrome.

Try changing your [config.txt](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt) and uncomment the line `sdtv_mode=2`:

```
# uncomment for composite PAL
sdtv_mode=2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say if you have a "composite in" on your TV you are likely to have an RGB LR (Red, Green, Blue, AudioLeft, AudioRight) input.

You will probably need one of these (apologies for the Amazon link) [SCART to 3 Phono & S-Video Adaptor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Switchable-Scart-Phono-S-Video-Adaptor/dp/B0018DE4ZU) to plug in the video phono (yellow) cable to your TV to get a colour signal (and it could explain why you are only getting monochrome currently).

Comment: so for audio wich cable I should use? jack 3.5 with two output?

Comment: yes, a single 3.5mm jack that has a left/right (red/white) audio out. these can then also be put into the scart adapter. something like this : http://www.amazon.co.uk/NEEWER-3-5mm-Stereo-Audio-Cable/dp/B005MW0P38